# Permissionset Meta Data - Field level security

Tags: permission-sets

**Situation**

For few reasons it is necessary to keep track of all changes in salesforce. Especially permissions are very important. In oder to keep track of our administrators work we download every day all permissionsets and insert the content in  a git repo.

The same data is used for deployment.

I'm not able to locate the information about field level security in the XML files of my permission sets.

**Question**

- Are field level permissions part of the permissionset meta data?
- Is there any other way to keep track of field level permissions in permissionsets?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm#PermissionSetFieldPermissions_title)
2. Yes - the database. Query the [FieldPermissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm) and the [PermissionSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm) objects.